# Экспорт бд laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Моя проблема в том что когда я экспортирую бд. Вся кириллица слетает
Мой контроллер

```
public function export2()
{
    $table = Order_products::all();
    $filename = "test2.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array('sep=,'));
    fputcsv($handle, array('name','phone'));

    foreach($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, array($row['name'], $row['description'], $row['staticprice']));
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return Response::download($filename, 'test.csv', $headers);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, плиз

Comment: откройте в OpenOffice.ORG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эксель на windows понимает только кодировку windows-1251, следовательно вам необходимо конвертировать все ваши строки:

замените

```
fputcsv($handle, array($row['name'], $row['description'], $row['staticprice']));
```

на

```
fputcsv($handle, array(iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['name']), iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['description']), iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['staticprice'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf($handle, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
```

Добавьте эту строку после fopen()